# JS Window Open как обойти блокировку

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, есть ли актуальный способ обойти блокировку принудительного  всплывающего окна браузерами? `window.open('mysite');`

Answer (score 1):

Такие окна блокируются обычно браузером для защиты от всякого информационного спама, очевидно блокировку обойти нельзя, а даже если есть какая-то дырочка в браузерах которая позволит это сделать, её быстро исправят.

Если вы легально хотите открыть новое окно, то можно написать пользователю просьбу вручную разрешить сайту открывать новые окна. Либо организовать открытие нового окна в виде ссылки.